# How to get mobile push notifications on Jenkins jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, notifications

I'd like to receive automatic push notification to my mobile about completed Jenkins jobs and their status (success or failure) in any form. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For real push notifications you will need good amount of mobile contracts and infra.

Maybe you can consider using some kind of IM which will send you message to your IM

Comment: I agree, it would be a lot easier to setup something like direct slack notifications rather than custom push notifications since you can use the existing plugin as-is.

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins has a bunch of plugins:

- There's HTML5 [desktop notifier plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML5+Notifier+Plugin) which can push notifications to your browser
- There's a [Slack plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Slack+Plugin) which can push notifications to a Slack team/channel

Comment: Sathya, those notifications you talk about are different from mobile push notifications

Comment: @RomeoNinov in my defense, the post does say "push notification.. in any form" :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov what do you mean? Slack does mobile push as well... if you need something totally customized, you can invoke SNS through a post-build step, for example. But I would look seriously into anything that works wit IFTTT, or Zapier, first, before trying to do this myself.

Comment: @Sathya, the post say: "to my mobile" which mean for me mobile push notifications :) And bring notification on the screen is not push notification